# tbl_uvregression with coxph and cluster

Tags: r, cox-regression, gtsummary

I am  huge fan of the gtsummary package.
I am trying to get a univariate regression table using tbl_uvregression from gtsummary with method coxph.
I want to examine a cluster effect
`https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/3.4-0/topics/coxph`

I am not sure where and how to specify the cluster effect. Here's an example using the trial data from the survival package.

```
library(coxph)
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)
data(trial)
```

```
trial %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = coxph,
    y = response,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2),
  formula = "{y} ~ {x}+ (1|grade)"
  )
```

I have used the `coxph (Surv(time, status)` the output has different CI.
I assume, that `formula = "{y} ~ {x}+ (1|grade)`does not output the "cluster" effect.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `coxph()` function has a cluster argument that you can pass within `tbl_uvregression()`

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
library(survival)

trial %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = coxph,
    y = Surv(ttdeath, death),
    method.args = list(cluster = grade),
    include = -grade,
    exponentiate = TRUE
  ) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **N** | **HR** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Chemotherapy Treatment** | 200 |  |  |  |
| Drug A |  | — | — |  |
| Drug B |  | 1.25 | 1.15, 1.36 | <0.001 |
| **Age** | 189 | 1.01 | 1.00, 1.01 | 0.019 |
| **Marker Level (ng/mL)** | 190 | 0.91 | 0.79, 1.06 | 0.2 |
| **T Stage** | 200 |  |  |  |
| T1 |  | — | — |  |
| T2 |  | 1.18 | 0.71, 1.96 | 0.5 |
| T3 |  | 1.23 | 0.63, 2.42 | 0.5 |
| T4 |  | 2.48 | 1.77, 3.48 | <0.001 |
| **Tumor Response** | 193 | 0.50 | 0.34, 0.73 | <0.001 |

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>